# How can I access the bios remotely on a desktop computer acting as a server?

Tags: linux, monitoring, remote, bios, keyboard-video-mouse

What are the options for having remote control via network of a computer even down to the "bios" level. I've seen Dell's DRAC / Out-of-band management that they have for their servers, and typically is a built-in management card. I'm asking about more generic, non-rackmount machines that were not originally designed with this in mind.

I'd like to be able to remotely control whatever type of server I'm currently accessing - windows, linux, or mac - and be able to access it from either linux or mac. I'd like the type of control that would allow me to "press f2" (etc) and enter setup, change bios settings, interrupt the boot process, etc. It's OK if it is a 'video blocking' solution (i.e. nothing else can be plugged into the machine for video)

I've found the **[StarTech.com 1 Port USB PS/2 Server Remote Control IP KVM Switch](http://amzn.to/1HhNleL)** which claims to do what I'm asking for - but it's $400 and uses a java web interface :(

Are there any cheaper / lighter weight alternatives? I'm not opposed to a DIY type of solution.

Comment: $400 for a KVMoIP device is normal, and so is a Java web interface. I'm not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: Yes I think expecting cheaper and something that would allow connecting with one of the RDP protocols or maybe provided an X server.

Comment: Anything that runs within the OS is not going to give you access to the BIOS or to the computer/server during POST. The item you've found is the type of item you need and unfortunately they tend to be rather expensive.

Comment: More details, please @cwd. Why do you need this?

Comment: This is one of the major reasons why we generally _do not_ have desktop computers act as servers.

Comment: Waiting for someone hacking a Raspberry Zero and emulating a USB keyboard and mouse, an AD converter on the video output. That looks like a great open source project for a pensionair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Out-Of-Band Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management).

The best solution is to use purpose-built equipment with the feature set and qualities that you need. There's no shortcut here.

It would be nice to know *why* you're requesting this functionality and what the core issue is. If you have machines that aren't intended to be remotely managed, but have a need to support them (at the BIOS level) from afar, you may be using the wrong equipment.

Please provide some details about your specific situation.

Comment: Not sure if you saw that I mentioned Out-of-band management in the question? You are correct that I'm looking for a way to control machines remotely that were not intended to be managed remotely. I do not have a specific problem at hand but was curious if it was possible, easy, and/or common to do this. It seems like it could be handy / useful in a lot of scenarios.

Comment: It's not that handy. It's possible to manage machines remotely, But the need for BIOS-level access and the other value-add features that server-class OOB offer shouldn't be necessary for workstations.

Answer (score 5):

Buy computers with [Intel vPro](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/vpro/vpro-technology-general.html) built into the chipset or ship them to your end users with KVMoIP cards.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that was available but my when I mention "normal computer" in the question I meant computers that are not specifically purchased for this purpose. Also, not sure if Macs have the Intel vPro available...

Comment: Then your only option is KVMoIP cards to not block video, or KVMoIP devices if you can live with blocked video on the remote PC. I've used Lantronix Spiders for remote offices and guided remote support in hooking them up to PCs I need to work on, and then take them off when I'm done so the user can use the PC.

Comment: blocked video is ok for me - this would not be for desktop machines that are in-use

Comment: @cwd Some BIOSs/firmwares do have CLI tools as well.